# How to make elliptical inner shadow with CSS?

Tags: css

I want an elliptical inner shadow like this. It should fade to complete transparency on the left and right edges.

[image]

So far, I've only been able to attain the following. It doesn't even look like an ellipse anymore.

[image]

```
#someDiv {
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(
        50% 0%, 
        ellipse farthest-corner, 
        rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%, 
        rgba(255,0,0,0.00) 70%
    );
    border: 3px solid black;
    width: 30em;
    height: 20em;
}
```

Comment: I doubt you can without using Canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace `ellipse farthest-corner` with something like `70% 20%` and tweak from there.

edit: http://jsfiddle.net/ufLYQ/

Comment: Looks good on Webkit, but it doesn't work on Mozilla. I don't need it to work in IE.

Comment: Oh... well meh.  Sorry, not sure how in Mozilla, just looked at the spec and there's no apparent way to make an elipse.  If you really wanted to go crazy you could try setting the background of another nested div and then using transforms to smush it and place it at the top of the other div (which would now have to have `overflow:hidden`)

Answer (score 0):

These are pretty close to what you need:

I would use new style syntax for mozilla:
-moz-radial-gradient(center -10px, ellipse farthest-side, #ab0000, #ffffff 100%);

And something like this old-style syntax for webkit:
-webkit-gradient(radial, 325 -530, 600, 265 -235, 200,  from(white), to(white), color-stop(.8,red),color-stop(.9,red))

This will need some tweaking

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code For Elegant elliptical Shadow

```
<div class="box shadow-arch-center"></div>

.box {
  background-color: #9C9369;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.shadow-arch-center {
  position: relative;
}

.shadow-arch-center:before, .shadow-arch-center:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 10px;
  z-index: -10;
}

.shadow-arch-center:before {
  left: 2%;
  right: 65%;

  /* as box-shadows get smaller, opacities increase */
  box-shadow: 80px 0px 20px 22px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .01),
              70px 0px 20px 20px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .02),
              60px 0px 20px 18px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .04),
              50px 0px 20px 16px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .08),
              40px 0px 20px 14px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .16),
              30px 0px 20px 12px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .16),
              20px 0px 20px 10px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .25),
              10px 0px 20px 2px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .5),
              0 0 20px 2px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 1);

  transform: skewY(5deg);
}

.shadow-arch-center:after{
  left: 65%;
  right: 2%;

  /* as box-shadows get smaller, opacities increase */
  box-shadow: -80px 0px 20px 22px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .01),
              -70px 0px 20px 20px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .02),
              -60px 0px 20px 18px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .04),
              -50px 0px 20px 16px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .08),
              -40px 0px 20px 14px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .16),
              -30px 0px 20px 12px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .16),
              -20px 0px 20px 10px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .25),
              -10px 0px 20px 2px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .5),
              0 0 20px 2px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 1);

  transform: skewY(-5deg);
}
```